# CSS Wrapper Won't Align with its Content

Tags: css, design-patterns, layout, alignment, css-position

> I was trying to center my button with **margin 0 auto;** but it
>   appears to move more towards the right [Reference Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDveR.png) along
>   with my jumbotron line and as I inspect i saw that my **button wrapper
>   was not inline with my button** [Reference Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoiL2.png)

But as I ran my code here it seems to work fine:

```css
.view-products {
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  height: 160px;
  width: 115px;
  border-radius: 60% 60% 60% 60% / 75% 75% 45% 45%;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.view-products a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.view-products:hover {
  background-color: #eb974e;
  color: #ffcb05;
}

.view-products a {
  color: #eb974e;
}

.button-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 115px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row button-wrapper">
  <div class="col-12">
    <a href="products.html">
      <button type="button" class="view-products btn btn-primary">VIEW<br>PRODUCTS</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

> What should I do to my button so that it would align to its wrapper?

I've already tried removing other objects and had same results, something must've been pushing my button as it is centered when i scroll [Reference Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEgZN.png) and it's not the **logo** or **navbar**

I'm new to web dev and this is my first portfolio project I would really appreciate anyone that could help me solve this as I've already tried a lot of methods only to see no difference.

Comment: Why `button` in the anchor tag `a`? That doesn't make sense. If you want to take the user to `products.html` than anchor tag is enough. You don't need a button. In fact, the button has no effect in this markup.

Comment: @CodeLover Thanks for your suggestion! I didn't know that anchor tag is already enough, thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, moreover, your CSS is targeting the wrong anchor. You have applied `.view-products` to button and targeting child anchor tag which doesn't exist. To your question, what I understood, you want a clickable element that looks like egg and text should be aligned in the center. Vertically and horizontally. Is that what you are looking?

Comment: @CodeLover Yes i was trying to center the actual button not the text but its wrapper seems to not align with my button as in Image Reference 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am yet not sure what exactly you are looking but I have tried to make based on what I understood.

With `btn-primary` class I believe you are using bootstrap.

First, you need to fix your anchor and button markup. Refer to the below snippet that may help you.

> **Note:** If you don't need `.row` container margin than remove `my-2`.

```css
.view-products {
    width: 150px;
    height: 208px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/PspKZF4.png");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row my-2">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="view-products d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <a href="#" class="text-center">VIEW<br />PRODUCTS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think i fixed it but i changed my col-12 to col-13 but doesn't bootstrap contain only 12 cols?(refer to my image in my own answer)

Comment: Thank you!! you fixed my problem it's actually justify-content-center that fixed it don't mind what I commented earlier your code actually helped me center my content I just didn't know that there's such a thing like d-flex in bootstrap Thanks again for helping a beginner like me!

Comment: Glad to help you. You learn more about bootstrap flex here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/ and the complete guide is here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/ Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the reason why margin 0 auto; didn't work based from what I searched, is because tags like <a> are inline elements, anyways thank you for helping me on my first time being here!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding    "margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;"    to       '.view-product'.
You can also try    'float:right;'    in     '.view-product'

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, I really appreciate it!, but I've already tried that I only wanted to know how to align my button to its wrapper as in Reference Image 2 its misaligned. 

This is my first time here at stack overflow thanks again!

Comment: No worries, I am new here too. Hope @Codelover's answer solved your problem. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

@codelover I think i fixed it but i changed my col-12 to col-13 but doesn't bootstrap contain only 12 cols? [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLrXG.png)

```html
<div class="row button-wrapper">
  <div class="col-13">
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='products.html'" class="view-products btn btn-primary">VIEW<br>PRODUCTS</button>
  </div>
</div>
```